# Get "path" of nested types as string in Swift

Tags: swift, string, types, nested, nested-types

#### The Problem

I'm searching for a generic way to obtain the full name of a nested type in Swift, i.e. when I define nested structs as follows:

```
struct A {
    struct B {
        struct C {
        }
    }
}
```

and I create an instance of `C`, then I want to have a method that returns the full path of that instance's type:

```
let c = A.B.C()
fullTypeName(c) // should return "A.B.C"
```

---

#### My Approaches

When I use

```
String(describing: type(of: c))
```

it only returns the last component `C`, i.e. the type name relative to the scope in which it's defined.

When I use

```
String(reflecting: type(of: c))
```

it actually returns the whole path but with some ugly prefix `__lldb_expr_22.A.B.C`.

I created a simple custom `String` initializer from this:

```
extension String {

    init<Subject>(describingNestedType: Subject) {
        let string = String(reflecting: Subject.self)
        let components = string.split(separator: ".")
        let path = components.dropFirst().joined(separator: ".")
        self = path
    }

}
```

which works very well:

```
let c = A.B.C()
let cString = String(describingNestedType: c)
print(cString) // prints "A.B.C"
```

but using the method `String(reflecting:)` worries me a little because

- noone can guarantee that it doesn't return some other prefix in certain cases or no prefix at all
- the function's description states that it's intended for debugging purposes only.

---

### So is there a way to get the (full) name of a nested type in a safe way?

Comment: class_getSuperclass should help

Comment: According to https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md: *“String(reflecting:) can still be used to get fully qualified names.”* – Unless I am mistaken, the first component is always the module name.

Comment: `__lldb_expr_22` is the module name. I presume you're running this from a playground?

Comment: Correct. Thanks for your input!